# Run out of flags while reviewing, skip or downvote?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, down-votes

I've been reviewing first posts and late answers lately and have come across the situation where I'd run out of flags without noticing, and not be able to flag a post that needs obvious attention.

What is the proper course of action in this situation? Is it better to skip the review and hope that the next guy sees that the post needs to be flagged (and isn't a "No action needed" spammer), or would it make more sense to downvote/comment?

I suppose if the content is undisputedly flaggable, then it is better to just skip... but I am curious to know what you all think. Would it ever make sense to downvote something that should actually be flagged?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running out of flags shouldn't change the way you downvote.  Use your downvotes in exactly the same fashion that you would when you *do* have flags.

Comment: When all of a user's flags are used up, does the review queue become a downvote queue?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: What if I usually flag and downvote at the same time? If I run out of flags... and simply downvote, does that not remove the post from the review queue? Would it not be better to skip in this case, especially if the post is of an offensive nature, so that others can flag? But then again... others might not flag. :-/

Comment: Well, I certainly wouldn't click "looks good" if it doesn't.  I don't see much benefit in reviewing entries in the Review Queue if one of your possible actions is disabled.  Wait until tomorrow, when you have more flags to use.

Comment: The one problem with only downvoting things is that I've seen a bunch of spam slip through this way. Some people simply won't flag anything they see in review, merely downvote when they come across spam or trolling, and that doesn't help us because it takes the item out of review and doesn't let us delete it immediately.

Comment: @BradLarson: Skipping does seem like the better option to me for posts that really need flagging (even if you risk the next guy just down voting). Waiting until tomorrow is certainly the best option, but if you fail to notice that you ran out of flags... you are still stuck with that one review.

Comment: @pschueller - Yeah, the only thing I could suggest would be to write down the URL somewhere so that you could flag it later. I know I've done that in the past. The important thing isn't the review, it's making sure the right thing happens with truly bad content. That's the whole reason we're reviewing, after all.

Comment: @BradLarson: Excellent suggestion! Not sure why I did not think of it, seems obvious enough and pretty much solves the dilemma. If you're checking the post again later anyway, then it doesn't really matter what you decide to do the day before.

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, if it is flaggable then it is most likely downvotable. If you aren't sure then I would at the very least leave a comment so that the poster can learn about what is wrong with it. I typically don't like to downvote loosy-goosy. If I think it is bad then I will give the poster a chance to fix unless it is just really terrible.

So by running out of flags doesn't mean you should just ignore (skip) it, IMHO. At the very least, leave a comment and hopefully either the poster will learn something or maybe others will agree and post the flag.

If its a first post then I probably wouldn't downvote rather, give them a comment on why it is a bad post. Most likely, they don't know what they do wrong and people seem to get crazy with downvotes and don't understand that most get the point after just a few.

Comment: Nice points :) Just wanted to add, if it is a first post, a link to the faq section is of much help too.